# How To get The Total of values in Flutter firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Collection 'Cart' contains a List of Products and every Product has a price so I want to get all of them and calculate the sum of prices :  [FireStore Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRvxv.png)

I tried a some of code and this one is working but how I can show the sum on the Screen

```
      Future getTotal() async {
    int sum = 0;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users/$userid/Cart').get().then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          for (var i = 1; i < result.data()['price'].toString().length; i++) {
            sum = sum + result.data()['price'];
          }
        });
        print('total : $sum');
      },
    );
    }
```

[image: Capture from Cart Screen]

Update : I Tried this is Working but when I delete a product from the cart the value didn't change Except when I Close The screen and then come back again ,

```
      double sum = 0;
       double total = 0;
      final String userid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

     @override
     void initState() {
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users/$userid/Cart').get().then(
        (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
          sum = sum + result.data()['price'];
          });
        setState(() {
          total = sum;
          });
        },
       );
      super.initState();
     }
```

any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Just create an instance variable, assign that your `sum`, `variable = sum` and then use it in your widget, for example a `Text('$variable')`

Comment: The question title and body isn't matching though!

Comment: It's good to change the title according to the body

Comment: it's better to set the total value in state and then you can get that total frim text widget

Comment: How I can do that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Works for me :

```
 final cartitems = snapshot.data;
            final List<CartModel> products = cartitems;
            double getPrice() {
              double price = 0;
              cartitems.forEach((x) {
                price += x.price * x.numofitem;
              });
              return price;
            }
```